# How to find difference beween two dates in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.currentDate=new Date();
$scope.currentDate=$filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');

//Value received from web service stored in data

$scope.login=data.last_login_server;
$scope.login=$filter('date')($scope.login,'yyyy-MM-dd');

if(($scope.login.getDate() + 30) == $scope.currentdate)
  alert('Time limit exceeded');
```

Comment: Use moment.js is the way to go

Comment: I would also have this check done in the ui state change or the route change as well. That way you can pretty much prevent them from going anywhere

Comment: What format is `last_login_server`? Can you create a `Date` from that?

Comment: use old fashioned javascript Date

Comment: Here is one way answered in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/5872769

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ellapsed time in milliseconds from two dates.

```js
var now = new Date();
var lastTime = new Date(/*data.last_login_server*/);
// set a date 30 days ago for demonstration
lastTime.setDate(now.getDate() - 30);  

var milliseconds = (now - lastTime);
var days =  milliseconds / 1000 / 3600 / 24;

alert(days);
```